# Sending data to BLE peripheral and check did has arrive?

Tags: swift, xcode

Trying to send data to peripheral, how to check if a message has arrived or not? possibly retry sending?

```
peripheral.writeValue(value!, for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)
```

Comment: `.withResponse` should trigger `peripheral(_:didWriteValueFor:error:)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518823-peripheral

Comment: I know, but it works only if I get a reply, what if the data was not provided? how to check ?